# SSIS Slowly Changing Dimension Connection Manager

Tags: ssis, scd

I am wondering if it is by design - when I try to configure the SCD object, why can I not use the Project level connection manager already defined?  Why do I need to create a new one?  Does the scope of the project level connection manager exclude SCD?

Comment: What versions are your SSIS project and the database you are targeting? On a side note: Maybe consider using [SCD Merge Wizard](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/SCD-Merge-Wizard) ... it may not be as comfortable as the oob SCD but is a huge improvement performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

The SCD component uses an OLEDB connection manager, so the dropdown will only filter those types of connection managers.  Most likely the project connection manager is another type like ADO or ODBC.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I appreciate it.  I will look into the different connection managers.